# Javascript do while loop not stopping

Tags: javascript, html, forms, loops

I am trying to create a calculation to take in a starting number, ending number, and step number to show all even numbers between start and end counting by the step value.
There seems to be something wrong with the logic of my loop as it will not stop and crashes.

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>

    <h2>JFinding all even numbers</h2>

    <p>Please input a starting number, ending number and step number:</p>

    Starting Number: <input id="start">
    Ending Number: <input id="end">
    Step by Number: <input id="step">

    <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Submit</button>

    <p id="demo"></p>

    <script>
    function myFunction() {
        var start, end, step, text;
        var result = [];

        // Get the value of the start number with start var
        start = parseInt(document.getElementById("start").value);
        // Get the value of the end number with end var
        end = parseInt(document.getElementById("end").value);
        // Get the value of the step number with step var
        step = parseInt(document.getElementById("step").value);
        console.log('start', start);
        console.log('end', end);
        console.log('step', step);
        // If start, end, or step is Not a Number or step is not even or start is greater than end or step is greater than end or start and step are equal to end
        if (isNaN(start) || isNaN(end) || isNaN(step) || step % 2 !== 0 || start > end || step > end || step === end || start === end) {
            //display text for invalid input
            text = "Input not valid";
            //display text to html page
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
            //else create a loop to find even numbers
        } else { 
            if(start % 2 === 0){
            for(var i = start; i <= end; i += step){
                          result.push(i);
                }
            } else {
                start += 1;
                for(var i = start; i <= end; i += step){
                          result.push(i);
                }
            }
            //sent the result to the html page
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = result;
    }
    console.log(result);
}
    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: `sum` will never increase past `start + step` because `sum = start + step;`  You likely want to initialize sum to = start and then change that line to `sum += step;`

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want to do is have

```
sum = start
```

Before the loop. And

```
sum += step
```

inside the loop

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the 3rd last line of your code. The line is about to push the var sum to the end of the result but you are pushing start variable instead, that's why the loop is not stopping

Answer (score 0):

Neither step nor start are changing during the loop, thus sum is not changing after each iteration.

You could change your code as follow:

```
sum = start;
do {
  sum += step;
  result.push(start);
}
```

You could also use a FOR loop to achieve the same behavior with easier syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of issues:

- When testing in Chrome, I needed to parseInt() the values in order work with them
- [isNaN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) only accepts 1 parameter at a time
- In our while loop, we need to increment sum, such as with `+=` or `sum = sum + step`
- We want to save the sum, not the start value
- We also want to check to see if the sum is a valid, or even, number
- Also, do while loops can be tricky to get the iteration while condition set up right so that you aren't doing one to many or too few iterations. And as we see, they can easily run endlessly if we don't have everything set up right. With that being the case, I'd recommend trying a for loop

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>

    <h2>JFinding all even numbers</h2>

    <p>Please input a starting number, ending number and step number:</p>

    Starting Number: <input id="start">
    Ending Number: <input id="end">
    Step by Number: <input id="step">

    <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Submit</button>

    <p id="demo"></p>

    <script>
    function myFunction() {
        var start, end, step, text;
        var result = [];

        // Get the value of the start number with start var
        start = parseInt(document.getElementById("start").value);
        // Get the value of the end number with end var
        end = parseInt(document.getElementById("end").value);
        // Get the value of the step number with step var
        step = parseInt(document.getElementById("step").value);
        console.log('start', start);
        console.log('end', end);
        console.log('step', step);
        // If start, end, or step is Not a Number or step is not even or start is greater than end or step is greater than end or start and step are equal to end
        if (isNaN(start) || isNaN(end) || isNaN(step) || step % 2 !== 0 || start > end || step > end || step === end || start === end) {
            //display text for invalid input
            text = "Input not valid";
            //display text to html page
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
            //else create a loop to find even numbers
        } else { 
            
            for(var i = start; i <= end; i += step){
                if(i % 2 === 0){
                    result.push(i);
                }
            };
            //sent the result to the html page
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = result;
    }
    }
    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Also note that the code requires the step to be an even number: `step % 2 !== 0`, so the only way we'll get any results is if the start number is even as well.